# AngularJS incorrect order of link functions

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

If I include a directive inside another directive's template and `transclude` the contents into it then its link function gets called before any of the transcluded directives.

For example (also on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/georeith/V3RQJ/2/)):

I have the following HTML composed of directives and templates.

```
<body ng-app="showcase">
    <reel>
        <asset></asset>
    </reel>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="reel.html">
      <div class="reel">
        <div class="inner" scrollable ng-transclude></div>
      </div>
    </script>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="asset.html">
      <div class="asset" ng-transclude></div>
    </script>
</body>
```

And set up my directives like so.

```
var app = angular.module('showcase', []);

app.directive('reel', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    templateUrl:'reel.html',
    link: function() { console.log('reel'); }
  };
});

app.directive('scrollable', function() {
  return {
    terminal: true,
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function() { console.log("scrollable"); }
  };
});

app.directive('asset', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    templateUrl: 'asset.html',
    link: function() { console.log('asset'); }
  };
});
```

The expected output into the console would be:

```
asset
scrollable
reel
```

Because `asset` is a child of `scrollable`, however I get:

```
scrollable
asset
reel
```

Does anyone know how I can get my order back but still define the additional directive within the `reel` template?

Comment: If you are using directives on the same element you need to set the priority.  By default user defined directives are priority of 0.  Try setting asset to priority: 10.

Comment: @CorySilva I used the `terminal` attribute to state its priority is always last. `ngTransclude` had a priority of 0 apparently.

Comment: @CorySilva Actually that worked... but it's weird the terminal property didn't. Do you want to make an answer and I will accept?

Comment: @CorySilva Sorry comment overload... I misunderstood the terminal property... it means any later priorities won't run. I thought it meant make it of latest priority no matter what.

Comment: Oops, I did not even notice you had the terminal property; I had the same first impressions of that property as well.  Glad you got it to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using directives on the same element you need to set the priority. By default user defined directives are priority of 0. Try setting asset to priority: 10.

### [Taken from AngularJS Code Comments:](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js)

```
/** ### Directive Definition Object
 *
 * The directive definition object provides instructions to the {@link ng.$compile
 * compiler}. The attributes are:
 *
 * #### `priority`
 * When there are multiple directives defined on a single DOM element, sometimes it
 * is necessary to specify the order in which the directives are applied. The `priority` is used
 * to sort the directives before their `compile` functions get called. Priority is defined as a
 * number. Directives with greater numerical `priority` are compiled first. Pre-link functions
 * are also run in priority order, but post-link functions are run in reverse order. The order
 * of directives with the same priority is undefined. The default priority is `0`.
 *
 * #### `terminal`
 * If set to true then the current `priority` will be the last set of directives
 * which will execute (any directives at the current priority will still execute
 * as the order of execution on same `priority` is undefined).
 */
```